# ShGetKnownFolderPath not working C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, environment-variables, windows-10

I want to get the AppData folder path by using the `ShGetKnownFolderPath` function in C++, which returns the `not declared in this scope` errpr. I tried alot of other functions like this one `SHGetFolderPath`, my headers are:

```
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
```

and the only thing which worked so far is `char *appData = getenv("AppData");`.
I am using Windows 10.

P.S

My question might look like a duplicate, but the answers to those questions didn't help me.

Comment: I guess (just guessing) you may have to define some macro to let your compiler use functions that only work with new enough Windows.

Comment: What type of app is this? Also did you define `WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT`?

Comment: You have to spell it correctly, capital S capital H.  And you have to set _WIN32_WINNT to at least 0x600 so it knows that you don't try to support an old version that doesn't have this function, like XP.

Comment: I spelled it correctly, believe me, i am making a console application, using MinGW.

Comment: I read other questions and their answers, but they do not work. It is stated clearly in the question isn't it?

Comment: Sorry if I am being rude, I'm just frustrated.

Comment: You probably didn't follow the instructions correctly `_WIN32_WINNT` has to be defined ***before*** you include any of the Windows headers. So you either need to put it at the very top of your code file, or perhaps even specify it on the command line.